# ajax function not found

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Getting error `TypeError: $.ajax is not a function` , i was creating ajax powered like button following this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkPRtQf6oQ8&t=387s 
site is django based

my script is

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

   <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
          function updateText(btn, newCount, verb){
          btn.text(newCount + " " + verb)
      }
      $(".like-btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        var this_ = $(this)
        var likeUrl = this_.attr("data-href")
        var likeCount = parseInt(this_.attr("data-likes")) | 0
        var addLike = likeCount + 1
        var removeLike = likeCount - 1
        if (likeUrl){
           $.ajax({
            url: likeUrl,
            method: "GET",
            data: {},
            success: function(data){
              console.log(data)
              var newLikes;
              if (data.liked){
                  updateText(this_, addLike, "Unlike")
              } else {
                  updateText(this_, removeLike, "Like")
                  // remove one like
              }
            }, error: function(error){
              console.log(error)
              console.log("error")
            }
          })
        }

      })
  })
```

Comment: Please confirm you have the full version of jquery and not the *slim* version (in your code, not here in the question)

Comment: ```<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>```thats the cdn using